# orderBy on whereHas query in Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

how can I sort the return data from a query using **whereHas**? In my query i have to get the users data which id exist on **interest** table but i need to sort it using the *datetime* column from **interest**. But, the return query do not sort the data at all.

Here's my code snippets in case it would help you understand my problem.

Model (name: User)

```
//***relationship***//
public function interest(){
     return $this->belongsTo('Interest','id','interest_by');
}
```

Controller

```
$userInterested = User::whereHas('interest',function($q) use ($id) {
     return $q->where('interest_on', $id)
              ->orderBy('datetime');
});
$userQuery = $userInterested->get();
return $userQuery;
```

Comment: oh, i manage to get the solution for my problem, using join() on query builder sufficed my need. But, if you have any other solutions, please feel free to post.

Answer (score 1):

remove return from where has and try this.like

```
$userInterested = User::whereHas('interest',function($q) use ($id) {
  $q->where('interest_on', $id)
          ->orderBy('datetime');
 })->get();
 return $userInterested;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$userInterested = User::whereHas('interest',function($q) use ($id) {
     return $q->where('interest_on', $id);
})->orderBy('datetime');
$userQuery = $userInterested->get();
return $userQuery;
```

Comment: tried it and its not working, it tries to look for _datetime_ on **users** table instead on **interest**